# Compiling U-BOOT bootloader on x86 Command

Tags: linux

make ARCH=arm  CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- -j4

what is the effect of "-j4 "in the above command   ?

Comment: *"-j [jobs], --jobs[=jobs] Specifies the number of jobs (commands) to run simultaneously. If there is more than one -j option, the last one is effective. If the -j option is given without an argument, make will not limit the number of jobs that can run simultaneously."* https://linux.die.net/man/1/make

Comment: what is the number("4")  indication  ?

Comment: how many threads will run in parallel, so you say 4 thread